# Rendering fails completely when nonzero stride is used in glVertexAttribPointer

Tags: opengl

I am trying to write a simple OpenGL 3 program. It works fine when the vertex buffer contains packed position elements, but not when there are other data members per-vertex.

The code below should work identically when Vertex is typedef'd to either SimpleVertex or ComplexVertex, but it doesn't.

```c
struct SimpleVertex
{
    glm :: vec3 position;

    SimpleVertex (float x, float y, float z) : position (x, y, z) {}
};

struct ComplexVertex
{
    glm :: vec3 position;
    glm :: vec3 normal; // Will be ignored in this example

    ComplexVertex (float x, float y, float z) : position (x, y, z) {}
};

// Fails when Vertex is ComplexVertex
typedef SimpleVertex Vertex;

GLuint vert_id;
GLuint index_id;
GLint  att_position;
```

Initialisation code:

```c
Vertex verts [] =
{
    {0, 0, 0},
    {1, 0, 0},
    {0, 1, 0}
};

GLubyte indices [] = {0, 1, 2};

glGenBuffers (1, & vert_id);
assert (0 != vert_id);
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vert_id);
glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof (verts), & verts [0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers (1, & index_id);
assert (0 != index_id);
glBindBuffer (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_id);
glBufferData (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof (indices), & indices [0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

att_position = glGetAttribLocation (shader_program_id, "position");
assert (att_position >= 0);

assert (GL_NO_ERROR == glGetError ());
```

Render loop:

```c
Vertex * dummy = nullptr;

assert (sizeof (glm :: vec3) == 3 * sizeof (GLfloat));

// In theory this should work regardless of the size or
// arrangement of members of Vertex.

glVertexAttribPointer (
    att_position,
    3,
    GL_FLOAT,
    GL_FALSE,
    // This is 0 for SimpleVertex, 12 for ComplexVertex, as expected
    sizeof (Vertex) - 3 * sizeof (GLfloat),
    & (dummy -> position));

assert (GL_NO_ERROR == glGetError ());

glEnableVertexAttribArray (att_position);

glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vert_id);
glBindBuffer (GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_id);

glDrawElements (
    GL_TRIANGLES,
    3,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    nullptr);
```

The vertex shader:

```
#version 130

attribute vec3 position;

void main ()
{
    gl_Position = vec4 (position, 1);
}
```

The fragment shader:

```
#version 130

out vec4 finalColor;

void main ()
{
    finalColor = vec4 (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

When Vertex is SimpleVertex I get an untransformed white triangle, fine. When I typedef it to ComplexVertex I get nothing at all. What's wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// This is 0 for SimpleVertex, 12 for ComplexVertex, as expected
```

Well there's your problem. Because that's certainly not what *OpenGL* expects.

The stride is the byte offset from the start of one attribute to the start of the next one in the array. It's the value that the implementation must use in this equation to compute the pointer to the `i`th element of the array:

```
baseOffset + (stride * i)
```

You are allowed to pass 0 for the stride. This tells OpenGL that the attribute is tightly packed, so GL will compute the actual stride by itself. But that doesn't mean the stride is *actually zero*; it's just telling OpenGL to compute it itself.

You should just be using `sizeof(type)`, so long as `type` is the actual type you're storing in your array.